# How to concatenate the values of a column based on some columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

| id | id_2 | id_3 | text | integers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | lorem | integers1 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | epsilon | integers2 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | text3 | integers3 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | text4 | integers4 |

My question is:

1. How can we merge text columns given the condition id, id_2 and id_3 are the same. I mean, I want to extract the values from 'text' column separated by comma or space and respecting the condition that id=0,id_2=1 and id_3=2
   Output wanted: 0 | 1 | 2 | lorem epsilon text3 | sum(integers1,integers2, integers3)

Thanks

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['id','id_2','id_3']).agg({'text': ' '.join, 'integers': 'sum'})`

Comment: ' '.join(what params should be here)? in the text aggregate